# How to Insert a Row before Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file that is used as a pandas dataframe, now I only need to insert a dummy row before the dataframe starts like in the screenshot denoted as "Label". How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: What do you want to do with the modified dataframe? What should the resulting index and column names be? Or do you want to simply create a new CSV file with the new first row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by someone in SO, but I can't find it now.

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    zip([' ']*256, 
        df))
```

He posted something like this, but doing it directly, will result in an empty row below the columns names row, so I did the following and it worked for me:

```
    df.index.name = 'time'
    df.index +=1

    df.reset_index(inplace=True)

    df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        zip([' ']*256, 
            df))

    df.to_csv(values["-OUTPUT_PATH-"]+'/converted.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with multi-indexing (see [more here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/cookbook.html#slicing)):

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools
import numpy as np
index = np.arange(9)
headr = [('label','time'), ("","a"), ("","b")]
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(headr)  
data = [[70 + x + y + (x * y) % 3 for x in range(3)] for y in range(9)]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index, cols)
df.to_csv('df_multiindex.csv', index=False)
```

[image: as csv]

or a bit easier try this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_csv_path_goes_here')
column_list = df.columns
index_array = [['label', column_list[0]]] + [['', f'{column_list[i]}'] for i in np.arange(1,len(column_list))]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_array)
df.columns = idx
df
```

should give something like this...
[image: updated]

Comment: is not there a more direct way? I have 255 columns, I don't want to reconstruct the whole dataframe.

Comment: updated my answer.